# How to get string between two repeating words?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string

I have been working on getting string between two words from a text file, in which these words are repeated several number of times.

What I have in my file;

```
 Name: Person1 
 Age: 20

 Name: Person2 
 Age:21

 Name: Person3 
 Age:22
```

What I want as output;

```
Person1 
Person2 
Person3
```

What I did so far;

```
Public Function StrBtw(ByVal Text_ As String, ByVal Start_ As String, ByVal End_ As String) As String
        Dim V As String = Nothing
        V = Text_.Substring(Text_.IndexOf(Start_) + Start_.Length, Text_.IndexOf(End_) - Text_.IndexOf(Start_) - Start_.Length)
        Return V
    End Function
```

Usage;

```
        Dim A As String = myFileString

        For i As Integer = 0 To A.Length - 1
            If i = A.IndexOf(W) Then
                TextBox1.Text &= StrBtw(A, "Name: ", "Age: ")
                i = A.IndexOf(W) + "Name: ".Length
            End If
        Next
```

Current Output;

```
Person1
```

As mentioned above, the output is showing only the name of Person1 while I want all names. I think that the possible cause may be with the IndexOf function being returned to the first "Name: " everytime. 
I tried using RegEx. I found it very confusing and the result is still the same. 
I've spent two hours on this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the problem is that `IndexOf` only retrieves the first occurrence in the way you use it. However, there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes the start index of the search as a parameter. You can use this overload and change your code like this:

```
Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim myFileString = "Name: Person1" & vbNewLine & "Age: 21" & _
            "Name: Person2" & vbNewLine & "Age: 21"
        Dim result As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim index = myFileString.IndexOf("Name:")
        While (index >= 0)
            Dim indexAge = myFileString.IndexOf("Age:", index)
            If (indexAge >= 0) Then
                result.AppendLine(myFileString.SubString(index + 5, indexAge - index - 5).Trim())
            End If
            index = myFileString.IndexOf("Name:", indexAge)
        End While
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The sample gets the first index without the additional parameter; the subsequent appearances are using the index of "Age:" as the starting point. You can run the sample [here](http://ideone.com/CFbwh7).

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code if you want to use regular expressions:

```
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(myFileString, "(?<=Name:\s).*(?=\n)", RegexOptions.Multiline)

For Each Match In matches
    Dim found As String = Match.ToString().Trim()
Next
```